# Django session working on local server but not on AWS server

Tags: django, amazon-web-services

In my Django view I use `self.request.user` to identify the user of a REST Framework API call. This works fine when the Django project is running on a server on my laptop, the code correctly picks up the user.

I am now trying to run my Django project on AWS EB and am having the problem that the `self.request.user` no longer identifies the user. The app code that is making the API call is exactly the same as is the Django server code.

Do I have to adjust my server settings in some way? My settings.py looks like this:

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

SECRET_KEY = '9-s0gj3$)(--+mgc^3qhy=iva#azu+7a@3='

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'grappelli',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.linkedin',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.twitter',
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_auth',
    'imagekit',
    #'blog',
    'storages',
    'items',
    'userprofile',
    'dashboard',
    'twip',
    'django.contrib.gis'
]

SITE_ID = 1

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                "django.core.context_processors.request",
            ],
        },
    },
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
    )

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

SOCIALACCOUNT_QUERY_EMAIL = True

SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'facebook': {
        'SCOPE': ['email', 'publish_stream'],
        'METHOD': 'js_sdk'  # instead of 'oauth2'
  }
}

# :TO DO: Remove this when we test proper email confirmation on the EB server. This sends confirmation email to the console
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'

# Postgresql database on AWS server
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': '',
        'USER' : '',
        'PASSWORD' : '',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Internationalization
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Berlin'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# STORE STATIC AND MEDIA FILES
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'yhistory'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'AKAAAA6AAAAYQ5JODCEA'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'AAAATtVeCZLaAAAAQQxZ9g5biTJnAAAA7PP8YrlC'
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME

# Location of static files
STATICFILES_LOCATION = 'static'
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = ( os.path.join('static'), )

# Location of media files (photos etc.)
MEDIAFILES_LOCATION = 'media'
MEDIA_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, MEDIAFILES_LOCATION)
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'custom_storages.MediaStorage'


REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': ['rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication'],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [],
    'PAGE_SIZE': 1000,  # Max number of results returned from a list API call
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ('rest_framework.filters.DjangoFilterBackend',),
    # Use JSONRender so the Web API interface is not shown. This is needed when testing the app on the same server
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    )
}

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True    # :PRODUCTION: Change this! If set to False the CORS whitelist is used
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = ()
"""
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'twip.co',
    '127.0.0.1'
)
"""
CORS_ORIGIN_REGEX_WHITELIST = ()
CORS_URLS_REGEX = '^.*$'
CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = (
    'GET',
    'POST',
    'PUT',
    'PATCH',
    'DELETE',
    'UPDATE',
    'OPTIONS'
)
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = (
    'x-requested-with',
    'content-type',
    'accept',
    'origin',
    'authorization',
    'x-csrftoken'
)
CORS_EXPOSE_HEADERS = ()
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = False

GRAPPELLI_ADMIN_TITLE = "The World Image Archive Admin Panel"
```

Comment: What happens if you delete session cookies for localhost? Seems like you have the user authenticated on local, but not on AWS

Comment: The API calls come from an iOS app. I have deleted the app and reinstalled.

Comment: I am not familiar enough with iOS. Are you sure reinstalling the app clears the cookie store? You could try and capture the HTTP traffic between the app and the server and see what you can see in the HTTP headers exchanged between the two. Or run the app in the dev emulator.

Comment: Uninstalling the app gets rid of all local storage associated with the app. I have checked the headers and they all look ok. The app is working exactly as before sending exactly the same headers, the only change was to move the Django code from a local server to AWS EB.

Comment: All I can say is that request.user is populated by Django authentication middleware. If you are not getting a user in `request.user`, it means that you are not authenticating with the app. From here on, you have a lot of layers where things might be going wrong. Did you generate API token for the user? Are you providing the right token? Are you using third-party authentication from allauth and missing some external configs? Since you don't provide either the client code or the endpoint code it is hard to tell.

Comment: As the only thing that has changed is that the Django code is hosted on AWS EB rather than my laptop I am assuming the issue lies with the Django code rather than my app (which works fine when the Django code is hosted on my laptop). I am struggling to see where in the Django code things are going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

possible solving options:

replace rest framework default authentication with the following snippet code

```
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    )
```

add this line in your settings.py file for details [click here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#apache-mod_wsgi-specific-configuration)

```
WSGIPassAuthorization On
```

Comment: Thanks Amir. My app uses token authentication which works fine when the Django code runs on my laptop. I did previously have the session authentication setting but had to remove this to get it to work.

What is the WSGIPassAuthorization On? Where do I put this?

Comment: I told you that to put "WSGIPassAuthorization On" in your settings.py file and gave you a details link. thanks

Comment: Thanks Amir that has fixed the problem.